# Delphi XE2/Win 7, setting Windows date time (SetDateTime) problems

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have a very basic understanding of the Windows security system and have two problems. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this.

**A)**  I have a Delphi XE2 application that uses a GPS clock to synchronize the system clock. The application runs under Windows 7. When trying to adjust the system clock by executing the windows function “*SetDateTime…*” I get a “Client doesn’t have the necessary privilege”. I’m running the application under my own account that has administrator privilege.

I then goto Controlpanel/Local Security Policy/Local Policies/User right Assignment” and change the policy “Change the System Time” to include my login account. Reboot the PC but still get the same problem with “*SetDateTime*” privilege.

Now if I start the Delphi application with “Run as Administrator” the application runs without problems. I don’t understand this. I thought by changing the user rights assignment I should be able to execute the “*SetDateTime*” function without resorting to “run as administrator”.

**B)**  When running as administrator as described above the application works as expected except one annoying problem. Every time the “*SetDateTime*” function is executed (the system clock is synchronized to the GPS clock) the application screen flickers (twinkles).

I suppose that is some sort of OS warning but I don’t like it and how can I eliminate this?

Comment: Windows does not have a `SetDateTime()` function. Do you mean [`SetSystemTime()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942.aspx) instead?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942(v=vs.85).aspx) clearly states that "special privileges" are needed, so you need to run as adminstrator before you can call the API.

Comment: And may I ask, why an application and not a service? This way you don't need to mess with privileges because the system account already has everything you need. If you need a GUI then you can make one that communicates with the service via IPC.

Comment: You don't need to add "change system time" right to you user since your user already has it, being an admin. The thing is that under UAC, you run with a restricted token and that right is removed. If you wish to change the time, you need to have sufficient privileges, for security reasons. You will have to do it in a service that has those privileges. One way or another.

Comment: If that's the only functionality of your application, you can change its manifest to require administrator privileges, so you don't need to remember to run it as administrator. It will then automatically trigger the UAC dialog. Somebody else suggested making it a service already, that's your other option.

Comment: You need to read on "user account control".

Comment: Thanks for advises. @Remy Lebeau Regarding SetDateTime/SetSystemTime I do use SetDateTime in my code. Further, SetDateTime is a Windows function as can be seen on this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393289(v=vs.85).aspx
Does anybody has a comment of the B question. Why does the screen flicker when the SetDateTime function is executed and how do you get rid of it?

Comment: @BoSM6FIE that link is for a WMI class method. Are you actually using WMI? Using WMI for this task is wy overkill when you can use `SetSystemTime()` directly instead.